# Axysimmetric Poisson equation solution

Tags: multivariable-calculus, legendre-polynomials, poissons-equation

I'm struggling to find the solution to the follow Poisson problem in spherical coordinates:

$$ \Delta\, f\left(r,\theta\right) = \sum_{l=1}^{4}k_{l} \left(r\right) P_{l}^{1}\left( \theta \right)$$

In the above equation $P_{l}^{1}\left( \theta \right)$ are the Associated Legendre polynomials of the first kind and the functions $k_{l}\left(r\right)$ are polynomials decreasing as $\frac{1}{r^{n}}$ with $n>7$.

Note that the problem is axysimmetric since the function $f$ and the right hand side do not depend the angle $\phi$, nevertheless the problem is $3$D.

The boundary conditions to the equations are:

$$
\begin{cases}f\left(1,\theta \right)&= -\sin\left( \theta \right)
\\
f\left(\infty,\theta \right) & = 0
\end{cases}
$$

I'm quite clueless on how to proceed, do you have any suggestion? maybe a particular form of $\ f\left(r,\theta\right)\;$ is helpful to find the solution?

(EDIT: this problem arise from the solution of the stokes equation with a body force where a sphere is free to move under the effect of the above mentioned body force field; if you feel that more details are required to the question I will gladly add them.)

Comment: There are no polynomials decreasing as $\frac1{r^n}$.

Comment: Because the $P_l^1$ polynomials are missing their $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi}$ factor, an expansion in spherical harmonics wouldn't terminate at finite $l$. So I don't see how to make use of the superficial similarity with spherical harmonics. You'll probably have to treat this as a fully general problem with cylindrical symmetry (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_harmonics).